# Tailwind CSS chevron animation on hover for dropdown menu from up to down

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I was wondering if there was a way to animate a chevron icon from up to down when you hover over a dropdown menu in tailwind css. My code is below. Any tips are appreciated and thank you. I used an HTML arrow in place of font awesome that shows it "up" just want it to show "down" on hover.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.4.2/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>


       <li class="mt-0.5 mr-1 text-2xl hover:bg-[#3B4E6A] hover:text-white">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-house mr-1 ml-0.5 inline"></i>
                <a href="#" class="text-2xl">Tools
           <!-- Chevron here  -->
                <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down fa-2xs ml-1"></i>&#8593;</a>
                <!-- Submenu starts -->
                <ul class="text-gray-800 w-full" id="dropdown-list">
                  <li class="leading-8 font-normal hover:bg-slate-200 items-center"><a class="text-2xl" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                  <li class="leading-8 font-normal hover:bg-slate-200 items-center"><a class="text-2xl" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rotate the chevron icon on hover by applying `transform: rotate(180deg)`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>


<li class="mt-0.5 mr-1 text-2xl hover:bg-[#3B4E6A] hover:text-white">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-house mr-1 ml-0.5 inline"></i>
  <a href="#" class="text-2xl">Tools
    <!-- Chevron here  -->
    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-up fa-2xs ml-1 [li:hover>a>&]:rotate-180 transition"></i>
  </a>
  <!-- Submenu starts -->
  <ul class="text-gray-800 w-full" id="dropdown-list">
    <li class="leading-8 font-normal hover:bg-slate-200 items-center"><a class="text-2xl" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="leading-8 font-normal hover:bg-slate-200 items-center"><a class="text-2xl" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks @wongin - not sure why i didnt try that :)